# Is it possible to determine how far into a wedge of a known angle you can place a circle of known dimensions?

Tags: trigonometry, circles, angle

Apologies for the title, I found it hard to express this succinctly in words alone!

Consider the following image, where `A` is a known angle (<=180°) and `d` is the known diameter of a circle. Is it possible to calculate the smallest possible distance (`x`) between the centre of the circle and the corner of the "wedge" `o`?

[image: diagram]

Comment: Hint: those outer black lines are perpendicular to the radius at the point of tangency.

Comment: I know what all those words mean in isolation, but I fear your hint has gone over my head! If i were to draw a line from the centre of the circle to the point the black line touches the edge of the circle it would be at right angles to the black line and be equal to the radius. what can I do with that information?

Comment: Now recall the definition of the sine and cosine of an angle in terms of the sides of a right triangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's $d/(2 sin(A/2))$. Draw a radius from the center of the circle to the point of tangency, and you have a right triangle with the angle $A/2$ opposite a side of length $d/2$, and a hypotenuse of length $x$. Solve $(d/2)/x = sin(A/2)$ for $x$ and you have your length.

Comment: This worked perfectly thank  you!